Can a "lone" magnetic field continue propagating after the electromagnet source is turned off?
In the context of an electromagnet generating a high-frequency magnetic field, is it possible to observe a "lone" magnetic field in space after the electromagnet is turned off?
To clarify, consider the following scenario: We use an electromagnet to emit a very short, high-frequency magnetic pulse (for example, at 1 GHz), then immediately turn off the electromagnet after emitting the pulse. The question is whether there will be a "lone" magnetic field, (generated during the brief activation of the electromagnet)continuing to propagate through space independently once the source is off. If this is the case, how does the magnetic field behave in terms of propagation, duration, and dissipation after the source is turned off?

What is a “lone” magnetic field? What distinction are you drawing with the word “lone”?

If by "lone" you mean without an accompanying electric field, then no; any time-varing magnetic field is also accompanied by an electric field. If you mean a pulse propagating through space without an "active" source then yes, that will absolutely happen

By "lone" I mean that, the source is off, but the magnetic field produced still exists and is continuing to travel in space.
we know that  the field strength drops by the inverse square of the distance from the source, but still stretches to "infinity".
if that's true, then it may need time to travel a certain distance. assume the field has moved 1 light second from the source, then the electromagnet is turned off.
Will the field that was 1 light second away continue traveling, or it ceases immediately?
(note: we are talking of a magnetic field from an electromagnet, no electric fields)
